# Does jQuery .click function perform every time?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, input, click

I work on a php file that contains a simple register form. I send the data to my mysql database via jQuery.click event. When the data goes to database, a massage display below the button, after 3 seconds it disappear and the input areas clean by jQuery. If I don't refresh the page and keep going to send data to my database, when I click the button, data go to database, input fields clean but message doesnt appear second time. I hope you could help me. Here is the jQuery code that I use;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(){
$.post("add_user2.php", $("#addUser").serialize(),  function(response) {
    $('#success').html(response);
    $('#success').hide(3000);
    $("#users_name").val('');
    $("#users_mail").val('');
    $("#users_phone").val('');
    $("#users_schoolnumber").val('');
    $("#users_faculty").val('');
    $("#datepicker").val('');
});
return false;
```

});
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
$('#success').hide(3000);
```

You are hiding your message box so when you execute it again, the message of the box will be the `response` variable but you will not see it as it is hidden.

You should show your message box when you want to display the message.

For example like:

```
$('#success').html(response).show();
$('#success').hide(3000);
```